# Exception on malloc for a structure in C

Tags: c, malloc, structure

I have a structure defined like so:

```
typedef struct {
 int n;
 int *n_p;
 void **list_pp;
 size_t rec_size;
 int n_buffs;
 size_t buff_size
} fl_hdr_type;
```

and in my code I Have a function for initlialization that has the following

```
fl_hdr_type *fl_hdr;
fl_hdr = malloc(sizeof(fl_hdr_type) + (buff_size_n * rec_size_n));
```

where those buffer size are passed in to the function to allow space for the buffers as well.

The size is pretty small typically..100*50 or something like that..plenty of memory on this system to allocate it.
I can't actually post the stack trace because this code is on another network, but some information pulled from dbx on the core file:

buff_size_n = 32, rec_size_n = 186

and the stack..line numbers from malloc.c

```
 t_splay:861
 t_delete:796
 realfree: 531
 cleanfree:945
 _malloc:230
 _malloc:186
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: What is the specific value of buff_size_n and rec_size_n when it fails ? What happens when it fails, you crash, or malloc returns NULL, or .. ?

Comment: Are you positively sure that it is the call to `malloc` that fails? Could either `buff_size_n` or `rec_size_n` be negative values? Have you tried replacing `malloc(sizeof(...) + ...)` with e.g. `malloc(5000)`?

Comment: Yes I know c doesnt have exceptions.

I am using dbx and I do a "where" command and it is definitely failing somewhere within the malloc call tree. I checked those values, and neither of them are ever negative. I do get a crash though, not just a return NULL

Comment: If you get a crash, you have a bug somewhere in your code, likely corrupting your heap.

Comment: You have heap corruption - probably an array overwrite somewhere else im your code.

Comment: The malloc itself cannot be failing. You can allocate any size you want to a pointer and the runtime will not care. The issue is what are you doing before or after. My suggestion is to narrow down the problem by creating a simple executable with only the parts you have causing the problem. Then post that. Once again this code is not correct, but it is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Can you provide the _full_ trace that glibc printed when it crashed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running your program through valgrind, see what it reports. It's possible in some other part of the program you have corrupted free lists or something else malloc looks at.

Comment: +1 If the program is crashing *inside* `malloc`, it is virtually guaranteed that you have corrupted the heap somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simply do this.

fl_hdr = malloc(sizeof(fl_hdr_type));
The list_pp is a dynamic array of void* and you need to allocate that to the size you need with another malloc.

list_pp is simply a pointer to something else that is allocated on then heap.

If you want to allocate in place with one malloc, then you will need to define it as an array of the actual types you want. The compiler needs to know the types to be able to perform the allocation.

If what you are looking for is dynamic arrays in C, [then look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260915/dynamic-array-of-structs-in-c).

Comment: Additionally, you need to do that to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made your example into a program, and have absolutely no issues running it. If you can compile and run this simple code (and it works), you have corrupted the heap somewhere else in your program. Please run it through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (*edit* as [User275455](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715454/exception-on-malloc-for-a-structure-in-c/2715557#2715557) suggested, I did not notice the reply) and update your question with the output that it gives you.

**Edit**

Additionally, please update your question to indicate *exactly* what you are doing with `**list_pp` and `*n_p` after allocating the structure. If you don't have access to valgrind, at least paste the entire trace that glibc printed when the program crashed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int n;
 int *n_p;
 void **list_pp;
 size_t rec_size;
 int n_buffs;
 size_t buff_size;
} fl_hdr_type;

static size_t buff_size_n = 50;
static size_t rec_size_n = 100;


static fl_hdr_type *my_init(void)
{
        fl_hdr_type *fl_hdr = NULL;
        fl_hdr = malloc(sizeof(fl_hdr_type) + (buff_size_n * rec_size_n));

        return fl_hdr;
}

int main(void)
{
        fl_hdr_type *t = NULL;

        t = my_init();

        printf("Malloc %s\n", t == NULL ? "Failed" : "Worked");

        if (t != NULL)
           free(t);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated the OP with what details i can get from the core file, but we do not have valgrind on that system..will have to look into that soon

Comment: And if you run this program by itself it fails ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly assign `n_p` and `list_pp` to the appropriate offsets.

```
fl_hdr_type *fl_hdr;
fl_hdr = malloc(sizeof(fl_hdr_type) + (buff_size_n * rec_size_n));
fl_hdr->n_p = fl_hdr+sizeof(fl_hdr_type);
fl_hdr->list_pp = fl_hdr->n_p + (num_n * sizeof(int));
```

If you're going to do this, I'd recommend putting the pointers at the end of the struct, instead of the middle.  I'm with Romain, though, and recommend you use separate calls to `malloc()` instead of grabbing everything with one call.

Comment: Allocating everything in one call helps reduce heap fragmentation.  Also, it's somewhat more efficient.  These aren't overriding reasons by themselves, but they can become important in some contexts.  If you do adopt the single-allocation approach, you need to be sure that the memory immediately after `*fl_hdr` is properly aligned for whatever it contains.