# Dynamic 2D char array

Tags: c

I want to allocate my 2D char array dynamically. Here I try to do this in cycle, but it gets me segmentation fault error. If I remove "arr[length] = str;" it will be ok. But it's not what I want to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char** arr;
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        arr = (char**) realloc(arr, (length+1) * sizeof(char*));
        char* str = (char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
        arr[length] = str;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out more about the issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting `arr` to `NULL` before the loop?

Comment: You never increment `length`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [two-dimensional dynamic array (realloc in c)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036408/two-dimensional-dynamic-array-realloc-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can do what Guido said but you can instead also set initially

```
char** arr = NULL;
```

because when realloc gets a NULL pointer as input it behaves as malloc.

Also the loop i assume must be

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
     arr = (char**) realloc(arr, (length+1) * sizeof(char*));
     char* str = (char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
     arr[length++] = str;
}
```

Notice the length++.

Answer (score 0):

You're using realloc on a `arr`, but you never allocated space for it. Use malloc

Comment: `realloc` should behave just like `malloc` if you pass in a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

According to manual:

> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed
>   to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range
>   from the start  of  the    region  up to the minimum of the old and
>   new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added
>   memory will not be initialized.  **If ptr is NULL, then    the call is
>   equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size**; if size is equal
>   to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to
>   free(ptr).   Unless    ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an
>   earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().  If the area pointed
>   to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

So, to use `realloc()` you should pass NULL pointer at first call to it. Thus, `arr` should be initialized to `NULL`.