# Trying to replicate an array for a fixed length

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I am trying to repeat elements of an array but stuck in an infinite loop 
the size of the array is currently 2 , I am trying to repeat these elements again to make the size 5, for example
sample output:
    `char a[]="ED";`
trying to make it
    `char a[]="EDEDE";`
the code is as follows

```
while(sizeof(a)<5)
{
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        a[fk]=a[i];
        fk++;}
}
```

goes into infinite loop

Comment: sizeof(a) is a fixed value

Comment: Writing to elements beyond the bounds of the array is an invalid operation(This is _undefined behavior_), not an expansion of the array.

Comment: You need to resize the array first, then fill it with contents. See [Resizing an array with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937409/resizing-an-array-with-c).

Comment: @Serge: Arrays defined as shown cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

> to make the size 5,

An array of any type `T` defined like this

```
T a[] = ... some initialiser ...;
```

or like this

```
T b[42];
```

cannot be resized (in C).

Answer (score 0):

**C11 6.4.5 String literals(P7):**

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

So, There is no resizing if you reassign a to something else, otherwise it is undefined behaviours.