# Is there a tuple datatype in C

Tags: c, types

I've been searching on the web for a while and cannot find anything. Is this datatype even available in c? If so can anyone link to a page on how to use them? I've been unable to find them so far....thanks!

Comment: What kind(s) of tuple are you referring to?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an array? What do you need a tuple for?

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't but using `struct` can be close enough in some cases. Try

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
} tuple;

tuple t = {1,2};

int main (void) 
{
    t.a = 3; // t.a == 3, t.b == 2
}
```

Comment: <code>typedef struct { // Tuple data structure created for k_request_process_status
 int pid;
 PCBState procStat;
 int priority;
}process_tuple;

typedef process_tuple * ProcTuple;</code>

Comment: Trying to generate an array of tuples.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260915/how-can-i-create-a-dynamically-sized-array-of-structs

Comment: I thought a tuple was an immutable list type? This example is mutable and is limited to 2 elements.

Comment: You can always use 'const int'.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing at the language level.

Will a `struct` suffice?

Comment: So I would have to make the data type myself? Is there no built in data type?

Comment: @Falcata: No, there is no built-in tuple datatype.

Answer (score 1):

The only types available in C are:

- built-in type: `int`, `char`, `long`, `float`, `double`, ...
- pointer to built-in types
- arrays
- struct
- enum
- pointer to function

Apart from that, you have to create them for yourself (even string, they are just an array of char terminated with a null character).