# how can i create a dynamic array of a hash table in c

Tags: c, arrays, hashtable, dynamic-arrays

i have the following bucket entry structure and hash table set up

```
typedef struct Hash_Entry
{
    struct Hash_Entry *next;    
    void        *key_Data;  
    unsigned    key_hash;   
    char        key[5]; 
} Hash_Entry;

typedef struct Hash_Table 
{
    struct Hash_Entry **bucketPtr;  /* Buckets in the table */
    int         size;       /* Actual size of array. */
    int         numEntries; /* Number of entries in the table. */
    int         mask;       /* Used to select bits for hashing. */
} Hash_Table;
```

I want to create an array(or a dynamic array) of this Hash_Table so that when I feel the table is full I can create another table instead of re sizing it

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
void hash_table_init(Hash_Table *table, size_t entries)
{
  size_t i;

  table->size = 0;
  table->numEntries = entries;
  table->bucketPtr = malloc(table->numEntries * sizeof *table->bucketPtr);
  for(i = 0; i < table->numEntries; i++)
    table->bucketPtr[i] = NULL;
  table->mask = 0; /* Not sure how to initialize this. */
}
```

I don't quite see the point of leaving the initial buckets as pointers, I'd probably just do

```
typedef struct {
  ...
  Hash_Entry *buckets;
  ...
} Hash_Table;
```

Assuming that most buckets will actually be used, so why not have them. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array using malloc from stdlib

```
Hash_Table* array = (Hash_Table*)malloc(sizeof(Hash_Table) * 100);
```

and when the array is full you can do a realloc.

you can have a look at:

[Create dynamic sized array of user defined structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260915/how-can-i-create-a-dynamically-sized-array-of-structs)

Comment: He said he doesn't want to resize that.