# How to define an array of structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have this structure :

```
typedef struct xmlelem{
Char         *Element_name;
Char         *Element_Text;  
pAttr_Element    attr_arr[M];
Xml_Element     *parent;
Xml_Element     *children[N];
Int         depth;
Int         num_of_children;
Int         num_of_attr;
}Xml_Element,*pXml_Element
```

I was wondering about the `children` and the `attr_arr` .
For the `attr_arr` - is it a pointer to an array where every cell is from type `pAttr_Element` or from type `attr_Element` ? How can I figure out if the cell is a pointer or the structure itself? How can I define both of them? I'm kind of lost..

sorry - here is the pAttr_Element:

```
 typedef struct {
   char *name;
   char *value;
 }Attr_Element,*pAttr_Element
```

another editing ,trying to be clearer

I understood thanks to the guys here that this is an array,where each cell is a pointer of type pAttr_Element.

I also understand now that declaring : Attr_Element[10] is an array where each cell is type of my structure

the only thing missing is how I define a pointer to an array where each cell is from type Attr_Element ? and not a pointer

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `pAttr_Element` defined ?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260915/how-can-i-create-a-dynamically-sized-array-of-structs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have assumed `attr_Element` is structure and `pAttr_Element` is typedef for type of pointer to this structure.

`typdef atr_Element* pAttr_Element;`

In this case, `pAttr_Element    attr_arr[M];` each element of attr_arr is a pointer variable to `attr_Element`. That means `attr_arr` is a array of pointer of type `attr_Element`

If you want to define array of elements of type `attr_Element`, directly use that type as below

```
#define SIZE_OF_ELEM 20

struct attr_Element attr_arr[SIZE_OF_ELEM];
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I'm misunderstanding something here , If it's an array of pointers to this structure, how can I define an array of structures ? using : attr_elment arr[10] gives me the array , but If I want a pointer to an array of structures? and not a pointer to array of pointers to structures, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If pAttr_Element is a pointer to Attr_Element, then attr_arr is an array of M pointers to Attr_Element.

In other words, attr_arr[0] is of type pAttr_Element, and attr_arr[0]->name is char*, and attr_arr[0]->name[0] is a char.