# File i/o to update the file in C

Tags: file-io

I want to update and compare the file.
How can I write code to get the following result?

1st run the program, get data `akon : 5`, and I need save into txt file:

```
akon : 5
```

2nd run, get data `john : 10`

```
akon : 5
john : 10
```

3rd run, get data `akon : 2`

```
akon : 2
john :10
```

4th run, get data `akon : 3`

```
akon : 3
john : 10
```

Below is the code I type, but I am stuck here.

```
FILE *out_file; 
char name[100];
int score;

printf("please enter name:");
gets(name);

printf("please enter the score:");
scanf("%d",&score);
out_file= fopen("C:\\Users/leon/Desktop/New Text Document.txt", "w"); // write only 

      // test for files not existing. 
      if (out_file == NULL) 
        {   
          printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
          exit(-1); // must include stdlib.h 
        } 

      // write to file 
      fprintf(out_file, "%s : %d",name,score); // write to file
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is here, or what the problem is with the code you posted. Can you [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking us to help you solve?

Comment: Don't use `gets()`; it is dangerous.  It isn't even a part of standard C any more (it was removed from the C11 standard).  Use `fgets()` instead; that doesn't give you buffer overflows.

Comment: Is the goal to read a name and score, and to update an existing entry with the same name with a new score, or to write a new name and score if the name is not already in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to prototype what you want first in a higher level language such as Python.  The following python code does what you desire.

You should be able to follow along with this code and find equivalent C methods to accomplish the same tasks.  The most complicated part will probably be deciding how to store the player/score pairs (in Python is is trivial, but unfortunately C does not have dictionaries).

```
# Equivalent to C/C++ include
import sys

# Create dictionary to store scores
data = {}

# Check for existence of scores files
try:
    with open("data.txt", 'r'): pass
except IOError: pass

with open("data.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        # Split line by ':'
        parts = line.split(':')

        # Check that there are two values (name, score)
        if len(parts) != 2: continue

        # Remove white-space (and store in temporary variables)
        name = parts[0].strip()
        score = parts[1].strip()

        # Store the name and score in dictionary
        data[name] = score

# Get input from user
update_name = raw_input('Enter player name: ')
update_score = raw_input('Enter player score: ')

# Update score of individual
data[update_name] = update_score

# Write data to file (and to screen)
with open("data.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for name,score in data.items():
        output = "{0} : {1}".format(name,score)

        print output
        fp.write(output + '\n')
```

A few tips:

- `fscanf(file, "%s : %d", name, score)` to replace most of the `split` and `strip` code.
- `struct { char* e_name; int e_score; } entry;`
- Take a look at this answer for arrays of structs https://stackoverflow.com/a/260981/2372604